# Vue Bootstrap: Align a button at the bottom of a b-col component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a grid layout that looks like this:

```
<b-container>
  <b-row class="vh-100 text-center" align-v="center">
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button></b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

[image]

I want to add a new button to the last `<b-col>` component, however, I want it aligned at the bottom of the column. I want the three "Create", "Search" and "edit" buttons still in line and vertically aligned at the center. Only the Red "Clear" button needs to be at the end of the `b-col` component.

```
<b-container>
  <b-row class="vh-100 text-center" align-v="center">
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col>
    <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button>
    <!-- The button below needs to be at the bottom of it's parent b-col -->
    <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Clear</b-button>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

I have tried so many different things and failed in achieving this.

Using a top margin doesn't help, I only ended up with something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simulate your situation in the below code snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
.customRow {
    align-content: flex-end;
}

.customCol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(50% + 19px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <b-container>
    <b-row class="vh-100 text-center customRow" align-v="center">
      <b-col class="customCol">
        <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button>
      </b-col>
      <b-col class="customCol">
        <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button>
      </b-col>
      <b-col class="customCol">
        <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button>

        <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>

</div>
```